Can AWS Lambda and API Gateway fully map and url, because azure function apps and apim can't
I have come up with the issue that I want all my Azure function apps to have the same domain and the same clean structure, which would allow me to produce a nice clean API.
something like
api.mydomain.com/v1/en-gb/tenent/222/product/create
however due to the way Azure apim (and all their front-end services) insert a suffix that has to be unique for all the function app between the domain and the route, there is no way to remove this, and there is no way to change it to a route which would be unique and there is no way to re-write the URL because there are no re-write policies on frontend urls.
so I am left with
api.mydomain.com/somestringofcharactershere/v1/en-gb/tenent/222/product/create
Does AWS have the same problem (or does Google)? any suggestions would be appreciated

Is using v1 as an API URL suffix in Azure API Management service not an option? You can also use complex API URL suffixes such as /v1/en-gb/tenent etc.

the suffix has to be unique across all api's added, so i could only add v1 as a suffix to one function app, you also cannot have dynamic values as part of the suffix so i cannot put the path as the suffix (thats what i want to do)

I probably don't fully understand the issue you are facing. You can have one API with suffix /v1/en-gb/tenent/222, another API with suffix /v1/en-gb/tenent/333, etc. Or you can have one API with suffix v1/en-gb/tenent/, and there you can have multiple operations with different URLs - /222, /333, etc. You can also use wildcards /* in the operation URLs. I don't think you have a problem that cannot be resolved in Azure API Management service. But I won't be posting answers here since the question is about AWS.

you can't use wildcards or dynamic paths in a api url suffix, * isn't allow, nor are { and }, so you can't have /v1/en-gb/tenent/{tennentId}, by i also don't want an api per tenent, i want a base url that looks like www.mydomain.com/{version}/{culture}/tenent/{tennentId}/products/get which you can't have if you import an api of function app

If your goal is to have a base URL like this - www.mydomain.com/{version}/{culture}/tenent/{tennentId}/products/get - it can be achieved differently, but indeed different APIs would have to be created for different {version} values. E.g. one API for v1, one for v2, and so on. If you can live with that, the rest can be achieved by using custom rewrite-uri (and possibly set-backend-service) policies. If you do not want to maintain mutiple APIs per {version}, then indeed API Management service alone can't satisfy your requirements.

i have over 50 app functions, i don't want v50,  the v is for versioning of the app function.

In this case, I can only suggest, in addition the API Management service, to look into routing offered by Azure Front Door or Application Gateway services. AFD or AGW would redirect requests to the APIM (which would be set up with a single API) - e.g. www.mydomain.com/{version}/{culture}/tenent/{tennentId}/products/get would be redirected to www.myapim.com/singleapi/{version}/{culture}/tenent/{tennentId}/products/get - and you know what to do from there (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/add-api-manually#add-and-test-a-parameterized-operation)

when i asked azure support earlier to say they said I would have the same problem with all other frontend services importing azure functions. However i come up with piggy backing apim with apim which would solve the problem but be twice as expensive, however there is a cheaper and easier option and thats to not import functions apps and create an http api manually and then manually configure each end point which is a massive pain but i get the result it want. i just can't post the answer yet.

You can do it, but you can't do it by adding an api as a function, you have the add only one api as a http end point, then add all the functions to this endpoint manually, i would add the policies but I am finding it can be a little wierd to how the rewrites are working.
also you have to add every method as well, its very time consuming but gets the required result.
